# IMAP and SMTP Still use Self Signed SSL even I have issued a Mail Server SSL in Cyberpanel

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, dovecot, imap

I using cyberpanel on CentOS 7 and I setup SSL for my postfix and dovecot. But I still got "SSL Invalid" caused the self-signed SSL even I have configure SSL using Lets Encrypt.

This is /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.net/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.net/privkey.pem
```

This is /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

```
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.net/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.net/privkey.pem
....
local_name mail.domain.net {
        ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.net/fullchain.pem
        ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.net/privkey.pem
}

local_name mail.sub.domain.net {
        ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.sub.domain.net/fullchain.pem
        ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.sub.domain.net/privkey.pem
}
```

This is /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf

```
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.net/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.net/privkey.pem
```

All file has pointed to correct SSL file. However, when I was trying to login IMAP and SMTP using SSL, I got error: SSL Invalid caused self-signed certificate [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (not mail.domain.net).

When I check using command: openssl s_client -servername mail.domain.net -connect mail.domain.net:993

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = US, ST = Denial, L = Springfield, O = Dis, CN = www.example.com
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Denial, L = Springfield, O = Dis, CN = www.example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1590 bytes and written 441 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 88F2CCFDE63FE391E9824F596E0C8300E44CB306F969E2A1C0AFE3B75E5A4D74
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: E22198E25F15AA193B9E73446CB934276DF90987DFC75B1B74DDAF3247CA8436CDB93B3274102188B3470DF1A4EFB0D1
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - e6 78 ae 14 e1 04 0d b4-64 82 65 9e 14 ad 32 9c   .x......d.e...2.
    0010 - f3 f0 c2 fd f9 12 5b bf-0f 50 75 79 64 5c bb ba   ......[..Puyd\..
    0020 - 31 f6 37 bd 1c b2 e7 dc-d9 02 c7 53 f4 f9 0c a6   1.7........S....
    0030 - d4 51 6a 60 6b 34 04 41-fd b3 7d 53 14 ff 1d b4   .Qj`k4.A..}S....
    0040 - a2 82 67 6e da d7 80 02-b0 9f 6d 82 b4 17 72 cf   ..gn......m...r.
    0050 - 30 05 54 fc 8c be 60 6d-e5 0f b8 25 04 f3 43 6d   0.T...`m...%..Cm
    0060 - 7e 13 f1 85 02 03 90 a2-50 82 64 43 aa 79 b8 ee   ~.......P.dC.y..
    0070 - 86 08 ef 7a ac 4b c7 86-57 bc 09 a4 9a bb 23 92   ...z.K..W.....#.
    0080 - cb 18 74 a4 90 c5 b1 8b-39 3c cc 69 ee e8 fb 08   ..t.....9<.i....
    0090 - 60 93 ea 17 35 d5 58 0d-ee 1b 68 c2 98 d0 e9 9c   `...5.X...h.....
    00a0 - f5 a7 24 9b 29 0a 48 6b-70 f8 a5 9a 7c e5 e8 88   ..$.).Hkp...|...

    Start Time: 1624855926
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
+OK Dovecot ready.
```

This is log on mail server.
systemctl status postfix -l

```
230, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown: SSL alert number 46, session=<RLYR5sLFeh62/Xx7>
Jun 28 00:42:37 mail-domain-net dovecot[574952]: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=182.253.XXX.XXX, lip=10.5.224.230, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown: SSL alert number 46, session=<WF4U5sLFlym2/Xx7>
Jun 28 00:42:38 mail-domain-net dovecot[574952]: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=182.253.XXX.XXX, lip=10.5.224.230, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown: SSL alert number 46, session=<nasX5sLFoim2/Xx7>
Jun 28 00:42:38 mail-domain-net dovecot[574952]: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=182.253.XXX.XXX, lip=10.5.224.230, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown: SSL alert number 46, session=<BFYY5sLFrCm2/Xx7>
Jun 28 00:42:38 mail-domain-net dovecot[574952]: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=182.253.XXX.XXX, lip=10.5.224.230, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown: SSL alert number 46, session=<YQkZ5sLFrSm2/Xx7>
```

Please help me, which file or config should I check.

Comment: Where do you see in logs the self signed problem ? I see a client in SSLv3, which should be forbid as obsolete technology

Comment: Did you restart dovecot and postfix after updating certificate? What is the output of `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -showcerts -connect mail.domain.net:25`? If you don't redact domains, people here can do such checks for you and provide an answer...

Comment: ssl_cert = </etc/letsenc really?

Comment: @Dom I saw that error in GMAIL apps and in python imaplib library.

Comment: @vidarlo yes, I have restarted dovecot and postfix after update config and certificate. However the output of openssl s_client -starttls smtp -showcerts -connect mail.domain.net:25 still using www.example.com (self-signed certificate).

Comment: @djdomi yes, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @xdnroot `ssl_cert = *<*/etc/letsenc` MUST be a misspelled, as `ssl_cert = /etc/letsenc` should it be - i see that it seems that you have a LOT of ** < ** in your config which dont have to be there!!

Comment: @djdomi I just follow the default config format and it confirmed in this docs: https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/dovecot_ssl_configuration/

Comment: strange behavior, never seen something like that

Comment: Have you tried any CyberPanel support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem by doing the following stuff:

**1. Configure PTR Record**
I request the server provider to add PTR record for my IP address. So, when you lookup your IP, it will returned this:

```
$ nslookup 116.193.250.253                                                                                                                   130 ⨯
253.250.193.116.in-addr.arpa    name = mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com.
253.250.193.116.in-addr.arpa    name = mail.yoursecondarymailserverdomain.com.
```

Alright, I used two domains for my email server.
If you still get self-signed SSL, go to 2nd step.

**2. Configure Postfix and Dovecot manually.**

Let say you are on some of the old versions of CyberPanel or you have already created a website before upgrading to v1.9.4. You can go ahead and create mail.domain.com as a child-domain to your master domain also make sure to issue SSL for this domain.

Step 1: Open the file /etc/postfix/main.cf using any editor

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Step 2: Comment the following two lines in that file by adding an # sign at the beginning.

```
# smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem 
# smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
```

Step 3:  Add the following lines after changing. Remember to replace YourPrimaryMailServerDomain with the your own domain.

```
# provide the primary certificate for the server, to be used for outgoing connections 
smtpd_tls_chain_files = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/privkey.pem, /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/fullchain.pem
```

Step 4: In order to support SNI you need to add the following lines at the end

```
# provide the map to be used when SNI support is enabled 
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
```

After all the above steps your files should look like this

```
# smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
# smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
# provide the primary certificate for the server, to be used for outgoing connections
smtpd_tls_chain_files = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/privkey.pem, /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/fullchain.pem
# provide the map to be used when SNI support is enabled
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
```

Step 5: Create a new file in /etc/postfix with the name of vmail_ssl.map

```
sudo touch /etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
```

Step 6: Edit the file to add your domain’s SSL certificates to the list like this

```
mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/fullchain.pem
```

Step 7 (Optional): If you have more than one domain to be supported add all of them one per line. The resulting file should look like this

```
# Compile with postmap -F hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map when updating
# One host per line
mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/fullchain.pem
mail.yoursecondarymailserverdomain.com /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yoursecondarymailserverdomain.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yoursecondarymailserverdomain.com/fullchain.pem
# add more domains with keys and certs as needed
```

Step 8: Open /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
```

Step 9: Append the following to the end of the file, replace domain.com with your own domain.

```
local_name mail.domain.com {
  ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/fullchain.pem
  ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/privkey.pem
}
```

Step 10: Re-compile postmap with SNI using the following command

```
postmap -F hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
```

Step 11: Restart Postfix.

```
systemctl restart postfix
```

Step 12: Restart Dovecot

```
systemctl restart dovecot
```

Connect again using a mail client and you should not see the error.

Reference: https://cyberpanel.net/docs/6-self-signed-ssl-error-on-outlook-thunderbird/

Good luck. :)